# Use Jolt to Transform Change Log JSON to Start/Stop Format

Tags: json, transformation, jolt, changelog

I'd like to use Jolt to transform the following JSON from its existing Change Log format to a From/To or Start/Stop format. Is this possible? Can you write a spec to do the transformation?

```
{
  "fields": {
    "status": "Done",
    "created": "2023-02-22"
  },
  "history": [
    {
      "created": "2023-02-27",
      "items": [
        {
          "field": "Status",
          "fromString": "In Testing",
          "toString": "Done"
        },
        {
          "field": "Priority",
          "fromString": "P2",
          "toString": "P1"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "created": "2023-02-26",
      "items": [
        {
          "field": "Status",
          "fromString": "In Progress",
          "toString": "In Testing"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "created": "2023-02-25",
      "items": [
        {
          "field": "Status",
          "fromString": "New",
          "toString": "In Progress"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "created": "2023-02-24",
      "items": [
        {
          "field": "Status",
          "fromString": "In Progress",
          "toString": "New"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "created": "2023-02-23",
      "items": [
        {
          "field": "Status",
          "fromString": "New",
          "toString": "In Progress"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Desired output:

```
{
  "statusHistory": [
    {
      "status": "New",
      "fromDate": "2023-02-22",
      "toDate": "2023-02-23"
    },
    {
      "status": "In Progress",
      "fromDate": "2023-02-23",
      "toDate": "2023-02-24"
    },
    {
      "status": "New",
      "fromDate": "2023-02-24",
      "toDate": "2023-02-25"
    },
    {
      "status": "In Progress",
      "fromDate": "2023-02-25",
      "toDate": "2023-02-26"
    },
    {
      "status": "In Testing",
      "fromDate": "2023-02-26",
      "toDate": "2023-02-27"
    },
    {
      "status": "Done",
      "fromDate": "2023-02-27",
      "toDate": "" // Blank because there is no end date for this status
    }
  ]
}
```

I've been able to use a "shift" operation to par down a larger JSON to the format above, but I'm completely lost as to how to progress further.

Comment: Can you please show how you tried to solve the problem

Comment: [
      {
        "operation": "shift",
        "spec": {
          "history": {
            "*": {
              "items": {
                "*": {
                  "field": {
                    "Status": {
                      "@4,created": ["@(3,toString).from", "@(3,fromString).to"]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]

I thought of trying to create a JSON object for each status (like above) but I don't know how to handle multiple instances of the same status.

Comment: I probably need to break this down into a number of issues rather than trying to address so many questions in one issue. I'm having trouble finding a good JOLT tutorial that describes the LHS and RHS operators in a way that I can follow them.

Comment: It's really hard to find a Jolt tutorial, but There are some links and blogs which I like, benefit and recommend such as [1](https://cool-cheng.blogspot.com/2019/12/json-jolt-tutorial.html), [2](https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt/releases), [3](https://erbalvindersingh.medium.com/applying-jolttransform-on-json-object-array-and-fetching-specific-fields-48946870b4fc), [4](https://intercom.help/godigibee/en/articles/3096940-simple-if-else-with-jolt), [5](https://intercom.help/godigibee/en/articles/3159219-transformer-operations-overview). Have a nice study!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a shift transformation spec such alike this one below based on the provided source values

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "0": {
              "fromString": {
                "@": "[#5].status",
                "@3,created": "[#5].toDate"
              },
              "toString": {
                "@5,fields.created": "[#5].fromDate"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // in order to order by the date
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "@toDate"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "sort"
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "statusHistory[#2].&"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the value for the attribute `"fromDate"` is set to `"2023-02-22"` for all occurences of the objects, since there is no individual data per each start.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! That's really close. 

This last step is where it gets really complicated. The "fromDate" for each status should be the "created" date on the item where the status appeared in the "toString" value. So for the first "In Progress" instance it is "2023-02-23" and the second "In Progress" instance it is "2023-02-25".

There will always be at least one status without a matching "toString" instance. In this case, it is the "New" status. The "fromDate" in that case should equal the "created" date in the "fields" section.